# xspf player remove album cover

Tags: flash, xspf

I'm trying to embed this player to a web page:

http://musicplayer.sourceforge.net/

It's working fine, but I would like to remove the album cover from the player so it looks like on this page:

http://www.hideout.com.br/blog/  (The gray player in the right column, not the player in the center of the page)

I looked at the documentation and also the source of this page and I can't figure out how to do it.
Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same question - I just set the width of the `<object>` to `190` (that's what is used on the page you referenced) and it seems to have automatically removed the image area and just displays the playlist part.  So that should be all you have to do.

A quick experiment seems to indicate that if the width is `334` or less, the image area won't show up.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the player used on the page you mention is the Slim Original skin and can be downloaded at http://blog.lacymorrow.com/projects/xspf-jukebox/

Just thought I'd let people know.